# Multiple <input> tags using the same name. Is that fine?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have two  fields using the same name. When using Google Chrome to POST these two input fields to an ASP.NET MVC controller, the input field that appears closest to the top of the page takes precedence. This is a desired behaviour but can I safely assume that this behaviour will be consistent with older browsers that are as old as IE6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple fields with the same name, but yes, as you noticed the 1st will override the others (you may be able to read them, depending on your server software, I don't know ASP.NET).

If you want, you can add `[]` to the name to make it an array.

```
<input name="test[]" />
<input name="test[]" />
```

I don't know about ASP.NET, but in PHP `$_POST['input']` will now be an array.

Comment: Interesting you gave me some ideas just incase this approach fails. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No problem to have multiple fields with same name. They will each be posted regardless of the browser version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no, it is **probably** fine, but **may** lead to problems.

From the Knockout manual ([link](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/uniqueName-binding.html)):

> - Other technologies may depend on the assumption that certain elements have names, even though names might be irrelevant when you’re
>     using KO. For example, jQuery Validation currently will only validate
>     elements that have names. To use this with a Knockout UI, it’s
>     sometimes necessary to apply the uniqueName binding to avoid confusing
>     jQuery Validation. See an example of using jQuery Validation with KO.
> - IE 6 does not allow radio buttons to be checked if they don’t have a name attribute. Most of the time this is irrelevant because your radio
>     button elements will have name attributes to put them into
>     mutually-exclusive groups. However, just in case you didn’t add a name
>     attribute because it’s unnecessary in your case, KO will internally
>     use uniqueName on those elements to ensure they can be checked.